# ¿se pueden hacer aplicaciones PHP para nw.js?

Tags: php, html5, nodejs

Recientemente estoy aprendiendo sobre nw.js  mis primeras apps de html5 las pude correr sin problema sin embargo quisiera ahora innovar con php y mysql pero al abrirlo en nw.js no lo reconoce y me sale el código escrito sin ser interpretado, ¿qué debo hacer para correr php con nw.js?, gracias  }

EL Package es el que siempre uso, me imagino que abra que "poner" a correr el php, pero no sé como.

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "main": "index.php"
}
```

Comment: ¿Dónde estás poniendo el código PHP?¿Puedes compartir un ejemplo del código que falla?

Comment: solo tengo el package.json {
 "name": "test",
 "main": "index.php"
}

Comment: Estaba viendo por encima este *nw.js* y por lo que veo no creo que pueda ser posible, primero porque necesitas un servidor si o si para poder ejecutar código `PHP`

Comment: Parece que se puede, pero no interpretando PHP en cada request como lo haría un servidor con fast-cgi o modphp, sino que empaquetando PHP (a la manera de un phar, supongo). No parece ser trivial: [php-webkit](https://github.com/baconface/php-webkit)